# How to reorder array sequence in draggable list

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

I'm using the `react-beautiful-dnd` component to create a draggable list.
I get backend data sorted by the `sequence` field.
After dragging and dropping the item, I use the `reorder` function to create a new list.
This is where I'm having problems! I need to create a new array by reordering the 'sequence' field based on `newItems`
to save the new string in the backend.
How can I do this?

**Initial result**

```
[
  { "id": 81,  "sequence": 14, "name": "Alaska" },
  { "id": 93,  "sequence": 26, "name": "Colorado" },
  { "id": 110, "sequence": 31, "name": "Kansas" },
  { "id": 121, "sequence": 43, "name": "Minnesota" },
  { "id": 132, "sequence": 52, "name": "New York" },
  { "id": 143, "sequence": 67, "name": "Virginia" },
  { "id": 164, "sequence": 78, "name": "Georgia" },
  { "id": 150, "sequence": 85, "name": "Florida" }
]
```

**Current result**

```
[      
  { "id": 93,  "sequence": 26, "name": "Colorado" },
  { "id": 110, "sequence": 31, "name": "Kansas" },
  { "id": 121, "sequence": 43, "name": "Minnesota" },
  { "id": 132, "sequence": 52, "name": "New York" },
  { "id": 143, "sequence": 67, "name": "Virginia" },
  { "id": 164, "sequence": 78, "name": "Georgia" },
  { "id": 81,  "sequence": 14, "name": "Alaska" },
  { "id": 150, "sequence": 85, "name": "Florida" }
]
```

**Expected result**

```
[      
  { "id": 93,  "sequence": 14, "name": "Colorado" },
  { "id": 110, "sequence": 26, "name": "Kansas" },
  { "id": 121, "sequence": 31, "name": "Minnesota" },
  { "id": 132, "sequence": 43, "name": "New York" },
  { "id": 143, "sequence": 52, "name": "Virginia" },
  { "id": 164, "sequence": 67, "name": "Georgia" },
  { "id": 81,  "sequence": 78, "name": "Alaska" },
  { "id": 150, "sequence": 85, "name": "Florida" }
]
```

[image]

[image: draggable-list]

***Reorder function***

```
const onDragEnd = ({ destination, source }) => {
    // dropped outside the list
    if (!destination) return;

    const newItems = reorder(items, source.index, destination.index);

    console.log(newItems);
    // Create a new array here!

    setItems(newItems);
  };
```

***Drag Drop component***

```
<DragDropContext onDragEnd={onDragEnd}>
            <Droppable droppableId="droppable-list">
              {(provided) => (
                <div ref={provided.innerRef} {...provided.droppableProps}>
                  {items.map((item, index) => (
                    <Draggable
                      draggableId={`${item.id}`}
                      index={index}
                      key={item.id}
                    >
                      {(provided, snapshot) => (
                        <ListItem
                          ref={provided.innerRef}
                          {...provided.draggableProps}
                          {...provided.dragHandleProps}
                          className={
                            snapshot.isDragging ? classes.draggingListItem : ""
                          }
                        >
                          <ListItemAvatar>
                            <Avatar>
                              <Add />
                            </Avatar>
                          </ListItemAvatar>
                          <ListItemText
                            primary={item.name}
                            secondary={`Sequence: ${item.sequence}`}
                          />
                        </ListItem>
                      )}
                    </Draggable>
                  ))}
                  {provided.placeholder}
                </div>
              )}
            </Droppable>
          </DragDropContext>
```

Comment: Basically `sequence` stays in the same order regardless, while the rest of the object properties follow their objects. Rather than having to update every object on every move you could simply store the `sequence` props in a seperate array and apply them to the objects just before writing.

Comment: Here's a quick [fork](https://codesandbox.io/s/reorder-draggable-list-array-forked-dgz4xo).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved, I implemented as indicated by @pilchard.
Thanks!

```
const [sequence, setSequence] = useState(data.map((d) => d.sequence));

const onDragEnd = ({ destination, source }) => {
    // dropped outside the list
    if (!destination) return;

    const newItems = reorder(items, source.index, destination.index);

    const newItemSequence = newItems.map(
      (el, index) => (el[index] = { ...el, sequence: sequence[index] })
    );

    setItems(newItemSequence);
  };
```

[See in CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/reorder-draggable-list-array-forked-xtpgch?file=/src/App.js:682-752)

Answer (score -1):

Try using `.sort` with your `sequence` property. Something like this:

```
const sortAscendingListByField = (list, field) => list.sort((a, b) => a[field] - b[field]);

const sorted = sortAscendingListByKey(yourList, 'sequence');
```